# ListView.builder saying widget can't be null

Tags: flutter, dart

My ListView.builder gives an error saying

```
The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.
Try removing the operator and the right operand

The return type 'Object' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context
```

Can someone explain what I did wrong? Or is there a way to make `PictureTile()` or `NotificationTile1()` nullable

newNotifications

```
List newNotification = ['liked', 'follow'];
```

ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: newNotification.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return newNotification[index] == 'follow' ?? PictureTile():NotificationTile1();
            },),
```

Picture tile

```
class PictureTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const PictureTile({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 70,
          width: 70,
          child: Stack(
            children: const [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  backgroundImage:
                      AssetImage('assets/images/ico-modified-rem.png'),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/sha-modified.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              Text(
                'Order Confirmation',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                'Order Cancelled',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 13,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Text(
                'You ordered Shawarma',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 13,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/chicken-shawarma-modified.png',
          height: 95,
          width: 91,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Notification tile

```
class NotificationTile1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationTile1({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotificationTile1> createState() => _NotificationTile1State();
}

class _NotificationTile1State extends State<NotificationTile1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        TileImg('assets/images/ico-modified-rem.png'),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 15,
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const [
            Text(
              'Order Confirmation',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Text(
              'Order Successful',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Text(
              'You ordered Shawarma',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return newNotification[index] == 'follow' ?? PictureTile():NotificationTile1();
```

to

```
return newNotification[index] == 'follow' ? PictureTile():NotificationTile1();
```

---

Or You can possibly use:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: newNotification.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (newNotification[index] == 'follow') {
      return PictureTile();
    } else {
      return NotificationTile1();
    }
  },
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the code

```
return newNotification[index] == 'follow' ?? PictureTile():NotificationTile1();
```

with

```
return newNotification[index] == 'follow' ? PictureTile():NotificationTile1();
```

Using (short if) is the best efficient way, also check this [blog](https://zetcode.com/dart/operators/) which will give a lot of information about operators.
if its work don't forget to vote ️.